# How I can Integrate my Compiler in VS2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, integrate

I make a compiler of Tiger and I want integrate with VS2008, but I read a lot of stuff and don't say very well how I can made that. What is the type of the project that I need to make? How I register my Language/compiler in VS2008, I know that I need install the SDK, I know little thing that I need to do but the steps more important, like What class I need to implement... Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166360.aspx

and possibly

http://mpfproj10.codeplex.com/

but there is a lot of scope of features here you may or may not want (implementing everything is a **lot** of work, so decide your priorities).

(Oops, I pointed you at the VS2010 bits rather than VS2008 bits; if you can choose to target VS2010 rather than VS2008, I expect the experience may be better.)